# Trouble dropping rows involving inherited models and relationships with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have (poorly) designed myself a DB that involves many relationships and inherited models as follows:

```
class Instrument(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'instrument'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    sn = db.Column(db.String(24), unique = True, index = True)
    ...
    data            = db.relationship('Data', backref = 'Instrument', lazy = 'dynamic', cascade = 'all, delete')
    sensors         = db.relationship('Sensor', backref = 'Instrument', lazy = 'dynamic', cascade = 'all, delete')


class Sensor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sensors'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    sn = db.Column(db.String(24), unique = True, index = True)
    ...
    data = db.relationship('SensorData', backref = 'Sensor', lazy = 'dynamic', cascade = 'all, delete')
    instr_sn = db.Column(db.String(24), db.ForeignKey('instrument.sn'), index = True)

class SensorTypeB(Sensor):
    __tablename__ = 'sensor_type_b'

    id      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensors.id'), primary_key = True)
    extracolumn = db.Column(db.Float)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'sensor_type_b'}

    def __init__(self, extracolumn = None, **kwargs):
        super(SensorTypeB, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.extracolumn = extracolumn

class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    timestamp   = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    value       = db.Column(db.Float)
    parameter   = db.Column(db.String(24), index = True)
    unit        = db.Column(db.String(24))
    flag        = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    instr_sn    = db.Column(db.String(24), db.ForeignKey('instrument.sn'), index = True)


class SensorData(Data):
    __tablename__ = 'sensor_data'

    id  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('data.id'), primary_key = True)
    sensor_sn = db.Column(db.String(24), db.ForeignKey('sensors.sn'), index = True)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'sensor_data'}

    def __init__(self, sensor_sn, **kwargs):
        super(SensorData, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sensor_sn  = sensor_sn

class MetSensorData(SensorData):
    __tablename__ = 'met_sensor_data'

    id  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor_data.id'), primary_key = True)
    raw = db.Column(db.Float)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'met_sensor_data'}

    def __init__(self, raw = None, **kwargs):
        super(MetSensorData, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.raw = raw
```

I have left out a good chunk for brevitiy..but can add in any details one might thing are relevant. The purpose of setting it up this way (in my mind) was to do the following:

- Every Sensor must belong to an Instrument, but not every Instrument must have a sensor
- All Instruments have data (`Instrument.data`)
- All Sensors have data (`Sensor.data`)
- The Child classes of the Sensor model have data (`SensorTypeB.data`)

Everything works as expected until I try to drop data points from the DB. It works perfectly fine in unittesting using SQLite3, but as soon as I move it to MySQL, everything breaks with the error of type:

```
IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`met
_sensor_data`, CONSTRAINT `met_sensor_data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `sensor_data` (`id`))') [SQL: u'DELETE FROM sensor_data WHE
RE sensor_data.id = %s'] [parameters: (3L,)]
```

Why does this happen only on MySQL and not SQLite? How can I fix and/or improve it? Is this not the worst DB design ever?

Comment: SQLite doesn't enforce foreign keys by default.

Comment: Right. So how do I either force MySQL to not pay attention to FK on delete, or design my schema in a way that doesn't have this issue across DBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you get is telling you that you are trying to delete a `SensorData` row, but in doing so, an entry in the `MetSensorData` that references it would be orphaned, and because of the way SQLAlchemy configures the relationship between `SensorData` and `MetSensorData`, orphans in `MetSensorData` are not allowed.

If you can find a way to not need that class, or to make it be a stand-alone model instead of an extension of the `SensorData` model, then your problem will go away. If you want to keep the model as it is, then you can add a cascade clause to the `SensorData` foreign key that instructs the database to remove the orphaned row instead of complain about it. I haven't tested it to make sure this is the right syntax, but I think you would do it as follows:

```
id  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor_data.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key = True)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. How does defining the cascade on the FK differ than defining it in the relationship, as I did above?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess is that your solution fails because it is applied in the Python space, not in the database space. If the database didn't enforce the PK, then in due time I think SQLAlchemy would have gotten that orphaned row cleaned up, but since this is done in two steps, after step #1 the db is in an inconsistent state that MySQL doesn't like. The SQL based cascade ensures that the deletion is done by the database.